# WinError 10061 on MQTT

Tags: python, mqtt, zeromq, paho

When I built about 5000 MQTT clients by using threading, I got the error message which is [WinError 10061] as following code.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import threading

def client(id):
    subscriber=mqtt.Client(id)
    subscriber.on_connect=on_connect
    subscriber.on_message=on_message
    subscriber.connect('192.168.233.142',keepalive=20)
    subscriber.loop_forever()

def on_connect(subscriber,userdata,flags,rc):
    if int(subscriber._client_id.decode())%1000==0:
        logging.info('連接伺服器')

def on_message(subscriber,userdata,msg):
    message=str(loads(msg.payload.decode()))
    if int(subscriber._client_id.decode())%1000==0:
        logging.info(message)


for i in range(5001):
    threading.Thread(target=client,args=(str(i),)).start()
    sleep(0.01)
```

I have seen this error before when I using ZMQ.SUB in another program, but the numbers of clients were over 10000.

Does too much connections make this problem?

If true, what makes these two package have the huge difference?

Answer (score 0):

Google says 'Win10061' is a "Connection Refused" error....so go look at the log file of your MQTT Broker and see what it says....that is where the error is occuring.

Most MQTT Brokers should be able to handle 5000 connections, but maybe you are starting them too close together and the MQTT Broker gets too busy trying to update its table of clients and push out CONACKs??

Where in your code does the error come back from??

Comment: subscriber.connect('192.168.233.142',keepalive=20)

Comment: So in your `client(id)` block, you might want to add some retry code of some sort. Retry a number of times and THEN die if unsuccessful. It could just be a timing issue with too many connects happening too fast for your Broker.